# Question about homotopy of paths and loops

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Are two loops with the same beginning and end point always path homotopic?

Comment: No. Take the constant path $\gamma(t)=(1,0)$ in $\mathbb S^1$ and the path $\gamma(t)=(\cos2\pi t,\sin 2\pi t)$ in $\mathbb S^1$. They are not homotopic, that's why the fundamental group of $\mathbb S^1$ is not trivial

Comment: Thank you, I hadnt thought of that, very helpful example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no! Let $\mathbb{S}^1 := \{z \in \mathbb{C}| |z| = 1\}$ and let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq 1$. Consider the following paths:
$$\alpha :[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1 $$
$$s \mapsto \exp(ins)$$
$$\beta :[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1 $$
$$s \mapsto \exp(-ins)$$
They are not homotopic but have the same initial and final point.